# How to achieve semantic search with ElasticSearch 8.4.2?

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp

I have a basic understanding of adding semantic search support for ES and added them below.
It would be beneficial if you guys share some working examples/code snippets for Semantic Elastic Search functionality.

**What’s a semantic search?**

It understands the contextual meaning of the word being used for search.

**How to achieve semantic search?**

[image]

Also, I have seen a working example of integrating ES with SemanticSearch
[image]

**Reference:** https://soumilshah1995.blogspot.com/2022/01/power-of-semantics-search-combined-with.html